# How does the put method of ConcurrentHashMap work?

Tags: java

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> playersPvpKills = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

String(key) is player name
Integer is the kills(of a game :P )

well if I use `playersPvpKills.add("stackoverflow25", 265);`

If already exist key stackoverflow25 but has another amount of kills, will it automatically update it to 265?

Comment: You could easily set up a small test case to answer your own question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [Map.put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.